# Prove that vectors $v_{1},v_{2} \cdots v_{n}$ are linearly independent if and only if matrix $\bf A$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I would like to prove following:

> **Proposition.** Let $S = \{\mathbf{v}_{1},\mathbf{v}_{2},...,\mathbf{v}_{n}\}$ be $n$ vectors in the $n$-space $\mathbb R^{n}$. Let $\mathbf A$ be $n$ by $n$ matrix whose columns are given by the vectors  $\mathbf{v}_{1},\mathbf{v}_{2},...,\mathbf{v}_{n}$:
>
> $$\mathbf A = (\mathbf{v}_{1}\mathbf{v}_{2} \cdots \mathbf{v}_{n})$$
>
> Then $\mathbf{v}_{1},\mathbf{v}_{2},...,\mathbf{v}_{n}$ are linearly independent $\iff$ $\mathbf A$ is invertible.

My attempt:

First, we assume that we've already proved following:

> **Theorem 1.** $\bf A$ is invertible if and only if linear system $\bf Ax = O$ has a
>   trivial solution $\bf x = O$.

$(\rightarrow)$

Suppose  $\mathbf{v}_{1},\mathbf{v}_{2},...,\mathbf{v}_{n}$ are linearly independent. Then we have

$$ k_{1}\mathbf{v}_{1}+k_{2}\mathbf{v}_{2} \cdots k_{n}\mathbf{v}_{n} = \bf O$$

Where $$k_{1} = k_{2} \cdots  = k_{n} = 0$$

Linear combination above can be rewritten as following linear system

$$(\mathbf{v}_{1}\mathbf{v}_{2} \cdots \mathbf{v}_{n}) \begin{pmatrix}
    k_{1} \\
    k_{2}  \\
\vdots \\
k_{n}
    \end{pmatrix} = \bf Ax = O$$

And because $\bf x = O$, by theorem 1, we conclude that matrix $\bf A$ is invertible.

$(\leftarrow)$ (This is actually identical to $(\rightarrow)$ but just going backwards)

Suppose $\mathbf A$ is invertible.

If we rewrite $\bf x$ as $$ \mathbf{x} = (k_{1},k_{2}...k_{n})^{T}$$

Then $\bf Ax = O$ can be rewritten as

$$(\mathbf{v}_{1}\mathbf{v}_{2} \cdots \mathbf{v}_{n}) \begin{pmatrix}
    k_{1} \\
    k_{2}  \\
\vdots \\
k_{n}
    \end{pmatrix} = k_{1}\mathbf{v}_{1}+k_{2}\mathbf{v}_{2} \cdots k_{n}\mathbf{v}_{n} = \bf O$$

And by theorem 1, we conclude that such linear combinatinon will be satisfied only when $$k_{1} = k_{2} \cdots  = k_{n} = 0$$

Hence if $\bf A$ is invertible, we can conclude  that $\mathbf{v}_{1},\mathbf{v}_{2},...,\mathbf{v}_{n}$ are linearly independent.

$\Box$

Is it correct?

Comment: Towards the end, you write '*only when*'. You should have emphasized the uniqueness from the beginning.

Comment: @Berci, could you tell me how exactly I should have done so, please?

Comment: E.g. the wording of Thm.1. should mention that $x=0$ is the *only* solution.

Comment: For the first part, start the proof with "Let $Ax = 0$, we must show that $x=0$." Then show that a linear combination of the columns comes out to $0$, invoke the hypothesis to get that all the coefficients in that combination must  be $0$, finally note that says precisely that $x$ is the $0$ vector, as desired.